# How can I get the k rows surrounding each row meeting a given condition in each direction of an R data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

`dplyr` solutions are preferred.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
library(tibble)

frame_data(
~a, ~b, ~c, ~d, ~e,
1, 2, 3, 4, FALSE,
5, 6, 7,8, TRUE,
9, 10, 11, 12, TRUE,
13, 14, 15, 16, FALSE,
17, 18, 19, 20, FALSE,
21, 22, 23, 24, FALSE,
25, 26, 27, 28, TRUE,
29, 30, 31, 32, FALSE,
33, 34, 35, 36, FALSE,
37, 38, 39, 40, FALSE
)
```

I'm looking to extract rows where the value in `e` is TRUE, and then also to extract a window of the `k` rows surrounding the row where `e` is TRUE in both directions, regardless of the value in `e`.  For example, if `k=1`, I want:

```
frame_data(
1, 2, 3, 4, FALSE,
5, 6, 7,8, TRUE,
9, 10, 11, 12, TRUE,
13, 14, 15, 16, FALSE,
21, 22, 23, 24, FALSE,
25, 26, 27, 28, TRUE,
29, 30, 31, 32, FALSE
)
```

and if `k=2`, I want:

```
frame_data(
~a, ~b, ~c, ~d, ~e,
1, 2, 3, 4, FALSE,
5, 6, 7,8, TRUE,
9, 10, 11, 12, TRUE,
13, 14, 15, 16, FALSE,
17, 18, 19, 20, FALSE,
21, 22, 23, 24, FALSE,
25, 26, 27, 28, TRUE,
29, 30, 31, 32, FALSE,
33, 34, 35, 36, FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

```
#selection window size
k<-1

#find row numbers
foundrows<-which(dat$e)
#create row index based on found row +- window size
selectedRows<-unlist(lapply(foundrows, function(z){seq(z-k, z+k)}))
#remove overlaps and out of bounds subscripts 
selectedRows<-sort(unique(selectedRows))
selectedRows<-selectedRows[selectedRows>0 & selectedRows<=nrow(dat)]

dat[selectedRows,]
```

Not quite as straight forward as using the lat/lead function but it does allow for easy adjustment of the window size.  It uses base R and will limit the row index to stay within the bounds for the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  I did something similar, but with tidyverse functions so I can easily quote and unquote variable names.